# Double Summation 666

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Arrange = $ ({a_{ij}}/ i=1,2,...,n ;j=1,2,...n+2)$.   How would yo expand this:$ {\displaystyle \;\ \sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=i}^{i+2}a_{ij}} $
Is this correct? ${\displaystyle \; \sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=i}^{i+2}a_{ij}=\sum _{j=1}^{3}a_{1j} + \sum _{j=2}^{4}a_{2j}+\sum _{j=3}^{5}a_{3j}+...+\sum _{j=n}^{n+2}a_{nj}}$

And how is the double summation expressed in the form $ {\displaystyle \;\ \sum _{j}^{}\sum _{i}^{}a_{ij}} $

Comment: What is $a_{n,n+2}$?

Comment: ${\displaystyle \; \sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum _{j=i}^{i+2}a_{ij}=\sum _{j=1}^{3}a_{1j} + \sum _{j=2}^{4}a_{2j}+\sum _{j=3}^{5}a_{3j}+...+\sum _{j=n}^{n+2}a_{nj}}$ is correct..




Why do you say 666 ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\{ a_{i,j}: i=1,\ldots,n \text{ and }j=1,\ldots,n+2 \}$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^{i+2}a_{i,j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n+2}\sum_{i=\max(j-2,1)}^{\min(j,n)}a_{i,j}.
$$

Comment: I´m not familiar with that notation $ min(j,n)$ anyways shouldnt it be $n+1$ ?? Thanks

Comment: @bajotupie $i$ can take, also as a function of $j$, only values between $1$ and $n$. Moreover, in the "middle", $i$ takes three values as a function of $j$; for the two extremes, just check its correctness ;)